# How to replace values of a given feature?

Tags: r

I have the following data frame

```
playRecords <- sample( c(T,F), 500, replace=TRUE, prob=c( 0.5, 0.5) )

df<-data.frame(play=playRecords,sunnyDay=rep(-1,500))
```

And I need to change the value of the `sunnyDay` first **6** observations which has `playRecords==T` and `sunnyDay==-1`

The following subset is those which should be changed

```
head(subset(df,playRecords==T & sunnyDay==-1,),6)
```

but **i don't know how safely to replace them with the current values in** `df`
only for that given 6 records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, it will work for you.
`inds <- which(df$play == T & df$sunnyDay == -1)[1:6]                                df$sunnyDay[inds] <- 1`